# How to save the initial startup configuration in IOS XR?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, cisco-ios-xr

I'm willing to try all the `Segment Routing` implementations one-by-one in `XRv 9000 Router`. Each time I have a specific implementation for `SR` e.g., `SR-TE`, `SR-MPLS`, `SR-OSPF`, and `SR-ISIS` ... etc.

The problem is in  IOS XR when the configuration is finished, you need to commit that configuration. How can I save the initial default configuration or the initial startup configuration in order to try out all the implementations to avoid ambiguity without losing SSH access to the router and the initial configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rollback to a specific configuration state with the command

```
rollback configuration to <commit-id>
```

You can see the commit-id numbers with the command

```
show configuration commit list
```